# Infinite sequence of exponentially distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Consider an infinite sequence of exponentially distributed random variables, $X_k$, where$ k \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ with $\lambda = 1$. I am trying to evaluate:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} (X_k)}{\ln n}.$$

So far, I have shown that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}E[[\dfrac{max_{1 \leq k \leq n} x_k}{log(n)}] = 1$$

If I show that the variance tends to zero in the limit, then I can assert that the limit is indeed 1. I am unable to do so.

---

Edit: I wrote a computer simulation of this process. In fact, the monte carlo method agreed that the expected limit is 1; however, even with over 1 million k values, I am not getting exact convergence. For example, I am getting number like 1.02 and 0.98 .

Here is the code for anyone interested:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/math/distributions/exponential.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions.hpp> // For non-member functions of distributions
#include <boost/random.hpp> // Convenience header file
#include <math.h>       /* log */

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Don't forget to tell compiler which namespace
    using namespace boost::math;

    double scaleParameter = 1;

    boost::exponential_distribution<> exp(1);
    boost::lagged_fibonacci607 rng;
    rng.seed(static_cast<unsigned int> (std::time(0)));
    boost::variate_generator<boost::lagged_fibonacci607&, boost::exponential_distribution<> > Rng(rng, exp);

    std::vector<double> vec;

    int lim = 1000000;
    for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
    {
        vec.push_back(Rng());
    }

    std::vector<double> xi;

    xi.reserve(vec.size());

    double max = vec[0];

    for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++)
    {
        if (*it > max)
        {
            max = *it;
        }
        xi.push_back(max);
    }



    vector<double> Log;

    for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
    {
        Log.push_back(log(i));
    }

    vector<double> eta;

    for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
    {
        eta.push_back(xi[i] / Log[i]);
    }

    cout << eta[lim - 1] << endl;




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If $X_1$,... are iid random variables which are not essentially bounded above then the limit of $\max(X_1,\dots,X_k)=\infty$ almost surely. Hint: If the limit is no larger than $1000$ then _all_ the $X_k$ must satisfy $X_k\le1000$.

Comment: I changed $\lim_{n->\infty}  max_{1 \leq k \leq n} (X_k)$ to $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \max_{1 \leq k \leq n} (X_k)$.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks. I am still trying to learn the syntax.

Comment: @MichaelHardy - could you suggest somewhere I can read about writing proper latex syntax?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - thanks so much for your help. I figured out the proof.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - Sorry to bother. The actual questions asks what is $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} X_k}{ln(n)}$. So I need to determine if the numerator grows faster than $ln(n)$.

Comment: So it's not quite so simple. But if every one of _those_ things is less than $1000$ then $X_n\le 1000\ln(n)$ for every $n$. Think about the probability of _that_...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich but when you take the limit as n goes to infinity, you get that $X_k≤1000ln(\infty)$,  $\forall n$. This seems okay. Doesn't it?

Comment: Google "latex symbols".  There's lots of stuff. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

It is absolutely not correct that at least one should be infinite.  It is true that for every real number $a$, infinitely many of the random variables will be more than $a$, but every one of them will be finite.  But the fact that for every $a>0$, infinitely many of them are $>a$ is enough to imply that the limit is infinite.  I'm going to follow up on David Ulrich's comment.  We're trying to prove that $$\Pr\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} = \infty \right)=1.$$  Notice that $\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ can only stay the same or get bigger every time $n$ is incremented by $1$.  It's monotone.  Every monotone non-decreasing sequence approaches a limit that is either some finite number or $\infty$.  Let $a>0$ be some finite number.  Consider
\begin{align}
& \Pr\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \le a \right) \\[10pt]
\le {} & \Pr\left( X_1\le a\ \&\ \cdots\ \&\ X_n\le a \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \left( \Pr(X_1\le a) \right)^n \to 0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for this. I made a very similar argument in my proof. I'm still not to sure how to deal with the log(n) in the limit though.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially asking for the distribution of the maximum order statistic of $n$ iid exponential random variables.  That is to say, what is $$\Pr\left[\max_{1\le k \le n} X_k \le x\right]?$$  Recall that $$\Pr[X_k \le x] = 1 - e^{-x}, \quad k = 1, 2, \ldots.$$  Since the $X_k$s are iid, it easily follows that $$\Pr\left[\max_{1\le k \le n} X_k \le x\right] = \Pr[(X_1 \le x) \cap (X_2 \le x) \cap \cdots \cap (X_n \le x)] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \prod_{k=1}^n \Pr[X_k \le x].$$  Now substitute to obtain the desired CDF, and differentiate to obtain the PDF.  Now compute the expectation of the maximum order statistic, scaled by $1/\log n$; i.e., $$\operatorname{E}\left[X_{(n)}/\log n\right] = \frac{1}{\log n} \int_{x=0}^\infty x f_{X_{(n)}}(x) \, dx.$$  Is this finite?  If not, what does this suggest?  If so, what would you need to do next?

---

Consider the function $$I(n) = \int_{x=0}^\infty xe^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^n \, dx.$$ With the substitution $u = 1-e^{-x}$, $du = e^{-x} \, dx$, $x = -\log(1-u)$, we obtain the equivalent expression $$I(n) = -\int_{u=0}^1 u^n \log(1-u) \, du.$$ Now the series expansion $$-\log(1-u) = -\int \frac{du}{1-u} = \int \sum_{j=0}^\infty u^j \, du = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{u^{j+1}}{j+1}$$ gives $$I(n) = \int_{u=0}^1 \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{u^{n+j}}{j} \, du = \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{j(j+n+1)} = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+n+1}\right) = \frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{j},$$ which one may recognize as $$I(n) = \frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1},$$ where $H_n$ is the $n^{\rm th}$ harmonic number.  Therefore the expectation is simply $$\operatorname{E}[X_{(n)}/\log n] = \frac{n I(n-1)}{\log n} = \frac{H_n}{\log n}.$$  Since we can establish the crude bounds $$H_n = \int_{x=1}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{\lfloor x \rfloor}  > \int_{x=1}^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} = \log(n+1) > \log n,$$ and $$H_n = 1 + \int_{x=1}^n \frac{dx}{\lceil x \rceil} < 1 + \int_{x=1}^n \frac{dx}{x} = 1 + \log n,$$ we then have $$1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log n}{\log n} < \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_n}{\log n} < \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1 + \log n}{\log n} = 1.$$  This establishes the asymptotic expectation is $1$.

One could then show that the variance tends to zero as $n \to \infty$, but this is more difficult if the method used is similar to that above.

Comment: Please can you explain what the maximum order statistic is.

Comment: The maximum order statistic of a sequence of iid random variables is simply the largest of the realizations; i.e., $$X_{(n)} = \max_{1\le k \le n} X_k.$$  For instance, if $n = 5$ and I observed:  $X_1 = 1.70574$, $X_2 =  0.736794$, $X_3 = 1.41265$, $X_4 = 1.81327$, $X_5 = 0.33517$, then the maximum order statistic of this sample is $X_{(5)} = 1.81327$.

Comment: I am trying to evaluate $$E[\dfrac{X_{(n)}}{log(n)}]$$. I have simplified the expression to $$\dfrac {n}{\log \left( n\right) }\int ^{\infty }_{0}te^{-t}\left( 1-e^{-t}\right) ^{n-1}dt $$. I don't know how to evaluate that integral. Any suggestions.

Comment: I even tried on Wolfram Alpha, gave very weird results.

Comment: where does the sum $$ \sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \dfrac{1}{j} $$ come from?

Comment: It is a telescoping sum.  For example, if $n = 3$, you would have $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+4} \right) = \frac{1}{1} - \frac{1}{5} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{9} + \cdots,$$ and you can see now that there will be cancellations.

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. But how does establishing that the expectation equals 1 help us establish the almost surely convergence. I was thinking about your suggestion: show that the variance tends to zero as $$ n \to \infty $$. So if the variance tends to zero, I suppose the expected value must tend toward the actual limit. Is this what you were suggesting?

Comment: Yes.  That is the idea.  However, the exact variance is hard to compute; it may be easier to find an approximation or upper bound, then demonstrate that the limit tends to zero.

Comment: I am trying to work straight from the definition of variance. It should be enough to show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{(\max_{1 \leq k \leq n}(X_k))^2}{(\ln n)^2}= \lim_{n\to\infty}  (\frac{\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} (X_k)}{\ln n})^2.$$. But I am stuck here!

Comment: I still cannot show that the variance is zero in the limit. I wrote a C++ simulation of the limit and I am not getting convergence. For example, for 1 million iterations the limit tends to 1.02 and 0.98 for example. I think this means that the limit does not exist?